# Having to press an asp.net button twice

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a button that sets a session variable when clicked.  But for some reason, I have to click it twice in order for the save to actually happen.  Is there anyway around this?

Thanks

```
     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

     If CInt(Session("save")) <> 1 Then
        'save something ...
     End If

     End Sub


     Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
           Session("save") = 1
     End Sub
```

Comment: You mean that you have an issue and it not saved in the first ? Correct that.

Comment: why don't you move the code in the page_load to the click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page_Load runs before btnSave_Click. You can see more information about the ordering of events in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#lifecycle_events).

In other words, when btnSave is clicked, the postback runs the Page_Load then the btnSave_Click method. To fix this problem, move the code 'save something ... into the btnSave_Click method.